# Java Observer Pattern not notifying

Tags: java, architecture, observer-pattern, software-design

For some reason my observers are not being notified when i call the notifyObserver methods, using the java.util.Observable objects:

here is my observable object:

```
public class ProjectManager extends Observable
{
...
 public void updateProjects(String project, String pack, String source, String ARN)
{
   ...
if(newSource)
    {
    tempPack.add(tempSource);
    System.out.println("Notify observers: " + this.countObservers());
    this.notifyObservers();
    }
      ...
      }
```

i can see from my output that the observer is being added but not being notified.

and my observer object looks like this:

```
public class IDE implements Observer
{

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

    System.out.println("Notified");

}
```

For some strange reason the observable object is not being notified at all. Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to `setChanged` before you `notifyObservers`

Comment: +1. Another reason to dislike Java's `Observable` implementation.

Comment: bit of a major gotcha but I guess it might make sense from a transactional point of view.